# Full Calendar Events not showing up

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web, fullcalendar

this is my code. There is no error but i don't know why my events are not showing up in the calendar.

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Events/GetEvents',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (list) {
                var events = [];
                $.each(list, function (index, value) {
                    var date = new Date(value.startDate.split(' ')[0]);
                    var start = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + value.startTime + ":00";
                    date = new Date(value.endDate.split(' ')[0])
                    var end = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + value.endTime + ":00";
                    events.push({
                        id: value.ID,
                        title: value.Title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: value.isFullDayEvent
                    });
                });
               callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but if you control your events source, you don't need to do any of that AJAX stuff.  Just use `events: '/Events/GetEvents'`.

Comment: No actually i have to do some customization on days colors as well which is now done and also events: '/Events/GetEvents' was not working for me

Comment: What did the method signature look like for '/Events/GetEvents'? I have it working with MVC 5, also you can set the background colour of an event server side too. You should be able to just call it and let it handle the json response.

Comment: Yes I'm exactly doing this. I'm handling in SQL Queries and sending the complex types to controller and then JsonConvert.Serialize(obj) will do the magic for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

```
 var date = new Date(value.startDate.split(' ')[0]);
                var start = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + value.startTime + ":00";
                date = new Date(value.endDate.split(' ')[0])
                var end = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + value.endTime + ":00";
```

These lines should be removed and date and time should be merged in c# before sending back to Ajax